# Adding asset to participant in hyperledger-composer: Error Message "Model violation ..."

Tags: hyperledger-composer

In my hyperledger-composer application, I have Consultants and Skills. Furthermore, I have a transaction called "UpdateSkillsOfConsultant", with which a skill can be added to a consultant.

However, submitting the transaction results in the following error message:

[image]

I have no idea what I am supposed to do with this error message.

I created a minimal example, that can be copied and pasted into the composer -playground.

This is the stuff to be copied into the model.cto file:

```
namespace org.comp.myapp



abstract participant User identified by id {
  o String id
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
  o String email
  o String password
}

participant Consultant extends User {

  --> Skill[] skills optional

}

asset Skill identified by id {
  o String id
  o String name
  o Proficiency proficiency
}

enum Proficiency {
  o Beginner
  o Intermediate
  o Advanced
}


transaction UpdateSkillsOfConsultant {
  --> Consultant consultant
  --> Skill[] newSkills
}


event ConsultantUpdated {
  o Consultant consultantOld
  o Consultant consultantNew
}
```

And here is the content of the script.js file:

```
 'use strict';



    /**
 * transaction UpdateSkillsOfConsultant
 * @param {org.comp.myapp.UpdateSkillsOfConsultant} transaction
 * @transaction
 */
async function updateSkillsOfConsultant(transaction) {

    // Save the old version of the consultant:
    const consultantOld = transaction.consultant;

    // Update the consultant with the new skills:
    const existingSkills = consultantOld.skills;
    for (newSkill in transaction.newSkills) {

            if (!transaction.consultant.skills) {
                transaction.consultant.skills = [newSkill];
            }
            else {
                transaction.consultant.skills = transaction.consultant.skills.concat(newSkill);
            }  

    } 

    // Get the participant registry containing the consultants:
    const participantRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry('org.comp.myapp.Consultant');

    // Update the consultant in the participant registry:
    await participantRegistry.update(transaction.consultant);

    // Emit an event for the modified consultant:
    let event = getFactory().newEvent('org.comp.myapp', 'ConsultantUpdated');
    event.consultantOld = consultantOld;
    event.consultantNew = transaction.consultant;
    emit(event);


}




//helper function:

function findSkill(array, name) {
    if(array) {
        for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].name == name) {
                return array[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

To reproduce the error just copy and paste everything in the composer playground, create a Consultant, create a Skill and then try to submit transaction "org.comp.myapp.UpdateSkillsOfConsultant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a javascript issue. The line

`for (newSkill in transaction.newSkills) {`

is returning the keys of the array (which would be 0,1,2...) if you only pass in 1 value to the array then it returns the value `0` which is the error you are seeing. Change the line to

`for (newSkill of transaction.newSkills) {`

that will fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much !  I thought I was going crazy